# Number of one to one functions $f$ [5] $\to$ [9] such that $rng(f)$ contains 7 as the greatest integer.

Tags: combinatorics, functions

for this question I would first like to know if the possible outputs for any particular function can be distinct, i.e. 1 2 3 4 5 all map to 7 or do valid outputs have to be distinct e.g. 1 2 3 4 7.

I am also asked to solve directly and then through consideration of the complement. The direct approach seems too be complicated but so far I have 7 fixed out of 5 choices so 5 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 functions which gives the same answer in confirmation with the complement approach.

Here is my complement approach,total - choices with 9 - choices with 8 - choices without 7 = (9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5) - (5 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5) - (5 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4) - (6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2). Compared to the direct approach, this gives the exact same result.

I need to know if there are any possible errors I made, i.e. overcounting or undercounting in either approach. Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly: number of functions from [5] to [9] with distinct outputs and the maximum of f being 7. Correct?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel yes

Comment: You've already said one-to-one, so the outputs have to be distinct...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yeah so it would then so I guess the fix would be 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 = 360.

Comment: Hmm... you've got the right answer now, 1800 functions, via the direct method. $\ddot\smile$